# Add route after Application_Start

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I am working on a site where the user is going to add pages to the site, and I was trying to use routing to immediately have the page available after creation.

For example, the user may create an About page, and right now I put some logic in the controller when the page is added.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Pages.Add(page);
            context.SaveChanges();
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(page.Name, page.Url,
                            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
```

But when I create the About page with About as the url and then try to go to /About, I get a 404 error.

Is it possible to add routes outside of the Application_Start?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Could you provide the whole picture? You should not be trying to add any routes in controller actions. There is a better way to achieve whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to make it so when someone adds a new page with a url such as /About, they can immediately browse to /About and it will use Home/Index as the default route for the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid defining any routes in controller actions. For your scenario you could define the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Now a request of the form `/About` will be routed to the `Index` action of the `Home` controller and passed `id=About` as argument:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    // if the request was /About, id will equal to About here
    ...
}
```